# RemoteWebDriver - Debugging headless docker containers

Tags: java, selenium, docker, remotewebdriver

Currently I am running a RemoteWebDriver through a docker instance, however I am struggling to debug this because the browser doesn't open so I can see it on my machine.

Here it the code that creates a driver - for some reason its always running in headless mode

```
public void createDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    String browser = propertyReader.readProperty("browserType");
    String opSys = getOS();
    String remoteDriverURL = propertyReader.readProperty("remoteWebDriverLocation");

    if (Objects.equals(opSys, "win")) {
        switch (browser) {
            case "firefox":
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), firefoxCap);
                webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
            case "ie": {
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), ieCap);
                webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
                return;
            }
            case "headless":
                chromeCap.setCapability("headlesss", true);
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), chromeCap);
            default: {
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), chromeCap);
                webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
            }
        }
    } else {
        switch (browser) {
            case "firefox":
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), firefoxCap);
                webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
            case "safari":
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), safariCap);
                webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
            case "headless":
                chromeCap.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
                chromeCap.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
                chromeCap.setCapability("headless", true);
                chromeCap.setCapability("window-size=1920,1080", true);
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), chromeCap);
            default:
                this.webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteDriverURL), chromeCap);
                webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
        }
    }

}
```

Is there anything which we can config so we can see the browser when running?

Comment: What is the error that you're facing?

Comment: Its not an error.. the tests run fine. However we want to be able to see the browser so we can debug - However the browser is running in headless by default.

Comment: Then why do you have cases for headless though ?

Comment: Two things, one docker containers are headless, second by setting the --headless capability there will be nothing to see when you try to attach to the container for debugging. See my answer below for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm approaching this assuming your are running selenium/hub, selenium/node-firefox, selenium/node-chrome. These are linux based images.

If you are running node-chrome and node-firefox, you want to change them to node-chrome-debug and node-firefox-debug, these versions come with VNC Server running on port 5900. I use docker-compose, and created a separate docker-compose-debug.yml for this type of issue:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    container_name: node-chrome-debug
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "5901:5900"
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    container_name: node-firefox-debug
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "5902:5900"
```

NOTE: the ports  5901:5900 and 5902:5900, these allow you to use VNC Client to connect to these nodes.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-debug.yml up
```

Basically, your nodes are headless but they still need something to simulate the browser gui, inside the container xvfb takes care of this for you. The debug versions of the nodes run a VNC Server which connects to xvfb. You run a VNC Client to connect to the VNC Server.

You will need a VNC Client, a popular version is [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/), download and install it on your machine. Put it where you like, make it executable and run it. I call mine vncview

```
>./vncview
```

This will launch a gui, you will give it an ip:port for the node you want to look at. e.g  127.0.0.1:5901 (my chrome debug) or 127.0.0.1:5902 (my ff debug)
password is "secret" - you will see the ubuntu logo. You can run two of these at the same time since we have assigned different ports.

Now just run your tests ;-)

*I've edited this answer to include the following:*

*Chrome has the ability to go completely Headless by using the --headless option, you have used this.*

*Selenium docker images run "headless" by default, containers have no display, xvfb is used to handle this. Xvfb fakes out the ui by creating/using a display buffer that never gets displayed.*

*Running chrome --headless on node-chrome, causes nothing to be sent to xvfb. So, if you later want to see what is happening just for debugging you can't.*

*You will need to remove the --headless option. This is not a disaster, as the docker selenium/node-chrome image defaults to "essentially" headless. I don't know if there is a time savings by using --headless on the docker image.*

also see:

[Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

[Selenium Grid with Docker](http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2016/10/13/selenium-grid-docker/) - lots of details with graphics

[docker-selenium debugging](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#debugging)

[Running Chrome in a Docker container](https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8)

Goolge terms: XVNC or VNC(virtual network computing) and XVFB (x vritural frame buffer)

Comment: If you are using one of the selenium/chrome-headless variants, you could substitute it in the docker-compose-debug.yml file above and add -p 9222:9222. Then you can use your host chrome   localhost:9222, this will give you access to the containers DevTools ... not exactly what you want [headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

The docker image is configured that way it uses a virtual frame buffer. But you can tell selenium to take screenshots whenever you want then you can save them into files.

Why are you using a RemoteWebDriver instead a regular one? If you want to see the browser running use a regular WebDriver or configure a Selenium Grid outside docker. You can check the Dockerfiles to see how the configured it.

Regards